# Unit-circle versus trigonometric approach to introducing Calculus

Tags: algebra-precalculus, trigonometry

I'm trying to decide on a text for a refresher in pre-Calculus. The publisher of two books by the same set of authors differentiates between them as follows:

> *Precalculus, Seventh Edition*
>   This book is the same as College Algebra with three chapters of trigonometry added. The trigonometry[sic] functions are introduced by a unit circle approach.

---

> *College Algebra with Trigonometry, Ninth Edition*
>   This book differs from Precalculus in that College Algebra with Trigonometry uses right triangle trigonometric[sic] to introduce the trigonometric functions.

What are the pros and cons, pedagogically speaking, to each manner of introducing trigonometric functions? What criteria would a teacher use to choose between the two?

Comment: When I first learned trig functions it was with right triangles, this was likely in high school but maybe even before that. I honestly don't remember. In college, we used the unit circle to make sense of the trig functions. I'm not a teacher but in higher level maths the unit circle approach seems to make the most sense. It also helps more in memorizing the basic results of various trig functions like at pi/3, pi/4, etc.

Comment: The students have presumably bumped into the right triangle approach already. If the course is to lead directly into calculus, the circle approach is preferable.